# How can I smoothly transform one periodic function into another if the period time is allowed to differ?

Tags: soft-question, fourier-transform, signal-processing, periodic-functions, smooth-functions

How can I smoothly transform one periodic function into another if the period time is allowed to differ?

Let us visit the very simplest example I can think of : Two audio signals pure sine waves.

Note A ($440$ Hz) and C ($523$ Hz).
There are probably many ways we can morph first into the other.

---

**Own work:**
Maybe the most straight forward solution would be :  $$\sin((\alpha(t) f_1 + (1-\alpha(t))f_2)t )\\ t \to \alpha(t)\\ t\in [0,1]\\\alpha(t) \in [0,1]$$
And $\alpha$ monotonically smoothly increasing.

This one is nice in the sense that we don't **need** to leave the set of $t\to \sin(ft)$ functions.

Maybe there exist other smooth solutions?

How could we express those?

Answer (score 1):

We can consider any smooth path that connects $f_0$ to $f_1$ in the complex plane. Assume $f_1 > f_0$. Let's simplify to the setting
$$\sin(\alpha(x)t) \ \ \ \  t \in (-\pi,\pi]  $$
$$ x \in [0,1] \ \ \ \ \alpha(0)=f_1, \, \alpha(1)=f_0  $$
An interesting example is the semicircle $\alpha(x)=0.5((f_1-f_0)e^{i\pi x}+f_0+f_1)$. Here is what happens during the transition when $f_0=1$ and $f_1=3$:
[image]

which is cooler if animated:

[$\hskip1in$ [image]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QqIS6.gif)

Comment: Nice imagery! While complex valued functions are easier to transport smoothly I don't know how to interpret them in an audio setting. Should I just discard the imaginary part?

Comment: @mathreadler yes that could be an option